# How do I list all the users?

Tags: drush

I would like to list information about all users using `drush`.

There is `user-information`, but it shows information only about single user.

Are there any other solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is recent sandbox project: [Drush User List](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/jbickar/2493771) (by [John](https://www.drupal.org/u/john-bickar)) which should work for Drupal 6 & 7 (see [GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/149)).

Usage:

```
drush user-list
```

For other workaround, the following command with process substitution syntax should help:

```
drush uinf $(drush sqlq "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM users")
```

However it could fail in some cases (when users have some special characters in their name).

Answer (score 14):

For Drupal 8 you could run the following command:

```
drush uinf $(drush sqlq "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM users_field_data")
```

The output will loke something like the following:

```
 User ID       :  1
 User name     :  admin
 User mail     :  info@example.com
 User roles    :  authenticated
                  administrator
 User status   :  1
```

Answer (score 9):

As kenorb pointed out, there is a workaround via SQL-query.

And with a minor change, it becomes more robust to special characters in names - by using "uid" (integer) instead of the user-names:

```
drush uinf $(drush sqlq "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uid) FROM users")
```

*PS: Confirmed for Drupal 7 only.
PPS: Sorry for adding another answer, I can not comment yet.*

Comment: it gives me only the 220 first users.

Comment: @lefterav: can you try the "SELECT" with "LIMIT x" (x being a larger number)?  
    `drush uinf $(drush sqlq "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uid) FROM users LIMIT 99999")`  
  
PS: Currently I do not have a Drupal-installation at hand, so I can now test for myself, sorry :-(

Comment: Drupal 8 & 9 syntax is: `drush uinf --uid=$(drush sqlq "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(uid) FROM users")`

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 8, there is a [Drush 9 command on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/richardbporter/drush-users-commands), e.g.

```
drush users:list
```

> List all Drupal users in a table format. See `drush users:list --help` for filtering options.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry... wrote this script for Drupal 8 remote machines with aliases; easily adaptable to local if necessary.

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
        echo "Usage : $0 sitealias [all/disabled/enabled] [rolename]"
        echo "Note: this only runs on Drupal 8 schema"
        exit
 fi

 ARG1=$1
 ARG2=${2:-all}
 ARG3=${3:-nothing}

 if [ "$ARG3" != "nothing" ]
 then
    ROLEWHERE='AND user__roles.roles_target_id="'$ARG3'"'
 fi



 case "$ARG2" in
    enabled) 
        WHERECLAUSE='WHERE users_field_data.status="1" '$ROLEWHERE
        ;;
    disabled)
        WHERECLAUSE='WHERE users_field_data.status="0" '$ROLEWHERE
        ;;
    all)
        WHERECLAUSE='WHERE users_field_data.status LIKE "%" '$ROLEWHERE
        ;;
    *)
        WHERECLAUSE=''
        ;;
 esac

 QUERY='SELECT users_field_data.uid,users_field_data.name,users_field_data.mail,from_unixtime(users_field_data.login) AS "lastlogin",user__roles.roles_target_id,users_field_data.status FROM users_field_data LEFT JOIN user__roles ON users_field_data.uid = user__roles.entity_id '$WHERECLAUSE

 drush $1 sqlq "$QUERY"
```